# Displaying User Logo After Upload + Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, paperclip

As a Rails newbie, I am running into an issue in which I can not figure out. I am currently using Devise for authentication and Paperclip for attachments. I have successfully added an upload field to the user edit and the image saves successfully.

My current setup right now is I have a header with a default Logo. I am trying to create a call that checks for if user has logo.

**Application Helper:**

```ruby
def logo_for(user)

if user_signed_in? && user.logo.present?
  image_tag user.logo_url(:small)
else 
  image_tag("logo.png", :alt => "Sample App", :class => "round")

   end
end
```

**_header.html.erb**

```ruby
<%= link_to logo_for(@user), root_path %>
```

**User.rb**

```ruby
has_attached_file :logo,
:styles => { :small => "150x150>" },
:url  => "/images/logos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
:path => ":rails_root/public/images/logos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
:convert_options => { :all => "-auto-orient" }

 attr_accessible :users, :logo, :logo_file_name, :logo_content_type, :logo_file_size, :logo_updated_at
end
```

I am receiving errors stating **NO HANDLER** undefined Method

How do I go about basically tapping into check if the user has uploaded a logo and have that display instead of default?

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple of things wrong in your `logo_for` method.

Try changing `user.logo.present?` to `user.logo?` which is functionality provided Paperclip (I believe).  Furthermore, your first `image_tag` reference should read as follows:

`image_tag user.logo.url(:small)`, notice I removed the underscore.

Comment: This is the error I receive:  **undefined method `logo?' for nil:NilClass**

Comment: Are you using Devise?  What is `user`?  If you're using Devise, it should probably be `current_user.logo?`.